# Are Linux kernel questions more suitable on this site or stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support

Are Linux kernel questions about OS concepts (which doesn't necessarily involve source code, for example, [Differences between system processes, and user processes, kernel control paths and kernel thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264416/differences-between-system-processes-and-user-processes-kernel-control-paths-a)) suitable on this site, Stack Overflow, both, or some other site?

What if the questions involve source code?

Answer (score 3):

If your questions are about *concepts*, why not try the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com)? OS questions are [on-topic](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/27761) there.

Comment: Because certain high profile users there tend to dislike questions that are not written  like from academia. Although there are users not like that, the former group of people always make the site hostile to nontraditional cs lovers.

Comment: So what? Are they the only users there?

Comment: Complain on their meta. Flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Have you actually had a meta discussion on this, before giving up? It is a graduated site, not *hopeless*.

Comment: Huh, look at that: [Gilles is a mod there](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). If you call that hopeless, I'm inclined to think it's you who are at fault.

Comment: Go post on their meta. That's all I have to say on the subject.

Comment: Not all moderators are like them. Gilles isn't amomg the people I mentioned. Patrick, a former moderator, constantly explicitly voice against their behavior and attitude in comment and chatroom, reopen closed questions and upvote downvoted. I like and miss what he did.

Answer (score 2):

For me it depends. If question is about how to install kernel, how to load module, how to config swappiness and so on this is definitely for here.

But if it's something like: I wrote process schedules and when compile it get this error" or "how to interact from C program to kernel" the question should be in Stack Overflow

In generally if it include source code should be directed to Stack Overflow (beside shell scripts). From other site I see there a lot of shell scripts and questions which will be more suitable for UNIX & Linux site